# Microsoft Excel Writer Step Unexpected Errors - Pentaho Data Integration 4.4.0

Tags: ubuntu, pentaho, kettle, spoon

I am using PDI 4.4.0 on Ububntu 14.04:

```
uname -a:
Linux LT0124 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I try to generate Excel file by using Microsoft Excel Writer Step I am getting following error:

```
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: File closed.
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : File closed.
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : 
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelwriter.ExcelWriterStep.closeOutputFile(ExcelWriterStep.java:225)
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelwriter.ExcelWriterStep.processRow(ExcelWriterStep.java:172)
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:50)
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: File closed.
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.apache.commons.vfs.util.MonitorOutputStream.assertOpen(Unknown Source)
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.apache.commons.vfs.util.MonitorOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:141)
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelwriter.ExcelWriterStep.closeOutputFile(ExcelWriterStep.java:223)
2014/05/07 23:39:26 - Microsoft Excel Writer.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   ... 3 more
```

When I try the same job with failing step on Ubuntu 12.04 and other machine everything is fine. I am sure that problem lies on my new Ubuntu 14.04 version and maybe it's related to the newest java version which I use:

java -version
   java version "1.8.0_05"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

Do you know what might be the reason?

Comment: Hi Tony, I am sorry what do you mean by POI?

Comment: Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents - http://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 2):

This is known bug using Java 8 and the Excel Writer step writing to XLSX files.  You must downgrade to Java 7 or 6 until it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?162417-Error-with-Excel-Writer&p=374426) maybe your problem is using an excel file version different from what it was supposed to be according to the task configuration.

Comment: Hi Felipe, this is not a reason here.

Answer (score 0):

As alread stated by Dave above, the problem is explicitly related to the .xlsx format in addition to Java RE version.

Hence, if you are not really relying on anything in the .xlsx format, it's probably easier to switch to the pre-2007 version Excel format, the .xls extension. For me (running Ubuntu 15.04 with OpenJDK RE build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14) it's working fine with .xls format, but failing with .xlsx